# Is cursor necessary in a multitasked system?

Tags: operating-system, multitasking

Does a multitasking system involve a mouse cursor to make the user able to interact with more than one task/process at a time?

Comment: I would not like to use any OS with out the text cursor of my console, be it multitasking or not.

Comment: Please rephrase this question. At the moment it sounds just as useful as "What difference does it make that I eat a banana while I fire up my multi-tasking operating system?". Also, try to ask *one* question at a time, it generally helps with the answers. If you leave this question as-is for a period of time, it will be closed and ultimately deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Unix, which is multi-tasking and multi-user, is often used without any sort of GUI.

Comment: This is extremely vague & unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a mouse to have a multitasking system. The [Wikipedia article on multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) has some history of multitasking systems; they're a lot older than window environments and mice. The first multitasking systems ran batch jobs: you submit a task (by loading up a deck of [punched cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card), for example) and wait for it to finish; there could be multiple tasks in progress at any given time.

Later systems had user interaction through a command line; for example, in a purely textual unix user interface, you can use [job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) to run commands in the background, and control which program you get to interact with.

Even in a typical window environment, the application that has the focus (i.e. the application that you type into) isn't the only one that can get CPU time. A window environment on a multitasking operating system lets you switch to another window while an application is computing something. Additionally pretty much any multitasking system has a bunch of tasks ready in the background, only running when some event happens (hardware event, packet received over the network, timer, …). So even when there are windows and a mouse, there's no particular relationship between them and multitasking.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing about a multi-tasking system that requires any kind of involvement by the user.

To tackle the banal answer, my system, which is a Windows 7 64-bit system, could start up Notepad and seem to be single-process only in the sense that I'm only running one program, but obviously that's far from the truth.

In the other end of the scale you could have a system where the concept of a mouse cursor wouldn't make sense at all, let alone a display. For instance, a mainframe would fit this end of the scale, where the system doesn't really have a user-interface or a mouse, but is still very much so a multi-user and thus a multi-process system.

I guess my answer is more like this: What is actually your question?